# iOS: Swipe between 2 Collections View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 Collections View Controller and I would like to swipe from the first to the second. Then, I am using the Swipe Component but it's not working on my application (not working at all).

Otherwise, I know how to use it between 2 simples View Controller Component but I would like to use it in Collections View Controller Component.

Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: put relevant code here ")

Comment: so what have you already tried

Comment: I have developped no code. I am only using WYSIWYG component with drag and drop. Well, this are my steps:

1) create project
2) Delete the "View Component" by default
3) Drag and drop a new "Collection View Controler"
4) Drag and drop a second "Collection View Controler"
5) Drag and drop a Swipe Component on the first "Collection View Controller"
6) Create a link between the Swie component to the second "Collection View Controler"

That's all :/ 

I don't think that I forgot something ...

Comment: You may want to rewrite your question using precise object names so readers can understand what you're talking about. Generally speaking, the easiest way to use gesture recognition that involves multiple collection views would be to attach the UIPanGestureRecognizer to the common parent.

Comment: Ok, so basicly I have created a new project. In this project, I have 2 components. The first: "A collection View Controller". The Second: "A collection View Controller". I want to use the "Swipe Component" to switch from one "Collection View Controller" to another.

To do that: I have put the "Swipe Component" on my first "Collection View Controller" and after that, I have created the link from the "Swipe Comp." to the second "Collection View Controller" through CRTL+Mouse. The link created is "Modal".
But, it's not working ...

Is it clear? (sorry for my english :/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do what you are asking, is to embed the view controllers in a `UIPageViewController`.

- Initialize using `– initWithTransitionStyle:navigationOrientation:options:`
- Set the initial view controller using `– setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:`
- Implement the datasource methods `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:` and `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:`

Don't forget to set the `datasource`.